# Using sphinx to auto-document a python class, module

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have installed [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) in order to document some Python modules and class I'm working on. While the markup language looks very nice, I haven't managed to auto-document a Python code.

Basically, I have the following Python module:

```
SegLib.py
```

And A class called `Seg` in it. I would like to display the docstrings of the class and module within the generated Sphinx document, and add further formatted text to it.

My `index.rst` looks like this:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
:maxdepth: 2

chapter1.rst
```

and `chapter1.rst`:

```
This is a header
================
Some text, *italic text*, **bold text**

* bulleted list.  There needs to be a space right after the "*"
* item 2

.. note::
   This is a note.

See :class:`Seg`
```

But `Seg` is just printed in bold, and not linked to an auto-generated documentation of the class.

Trying the following didn't help, either:

```
See :class:`Seg`
Module :mod:'SegLib'
Module :mod:'SegLib.py'
```

**Edit: changed SegLib to segments (thanks, iElectric!), and changed chapter1.rst to:**

```
The :mod:`segments` Module
--------------------------

.. automodule:: segments.segments

.. autoclass:: segments.segments.Seg
```

Still, can't get Sphinx to directly document functions within a class, or better - to automatically add all the functions within a class to the document. Tried:

```
.. autofunction:: segments.segments.Seg.sid
```

and got:

> ```
> autodoc can't import/find function 'segments.segments.Seg.sid', it reported error: "No module named Seg"
> ```

Any ideas how to auto-document the functions and classes with a short command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add to the beginning of the file:

```
.. module:: SegLib
```

Try using `:autoclass:` directive for class doc.

BTW: module names should be lower_case.

**EDIT:** [I learned a lot from reading other source files](https://almir.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_sources/api.txt).

Comment: In index.rst, for starters. When you documentation will get bigger, split it to multiple files.